# javascript .bind() is Not working on microsoft edge and Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This code is working perfectly on mozila(103.0) but, it is not working on chrome or microsoft edge.

```js
$('#loading').bind('ajaxStart', function () {
  $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

on console it gives Notice :

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
> its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.

Comment: 1) You have a missing `'` in the seelctor of your first jQuery object 2) What version of jQuery are you using? `bind()` was deprecated a ***long*** time ago. Update jQuery and use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.8.3

Comment: Update to 3.6 and try that

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/ - as of 1.9 global ajax events must be attached to *document* - so for 1.8.3 it *might* be ok, but for 3.6 will need some changes.

Comment: Any Idea on this notice ? > "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience"

Comment: That's a chrome message, because synchronous ajax requests on the main thread are deprecated (in Chrome) due to their detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.

Comment: i thinks it is preventing to load 
`$('#loading').show() `

Comment: I solved it with putting `timeout()` for ajax and, with putting
`$('#loading.se-pre-con').show()`  before `timeout()`

Answer (score 0):

As `.bind()` method is deprecated. You can use `.on()` method instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#loading').on('ajaxStart', function () {
    $(this).show();
  }).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say that you might forgot to wait for document being ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#loading').bind('ajaxStart', function () {
    $(this).show();
  }).bind('ajaxStop', function () {
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

Comment: This is working only for the mozila.